Self-hosted git Linux server with graphical front-end
For several reasons I'm going to install a git server on my VPS running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.
I know how to install a bare git server on a Linux machine, and I see some similar questions (like this) but I'm looking for the following features:

I need a front-end web-GUI server-side (not a local GUI on client machines!)
it should be free-of-charge of even a paid service but with no periodical subscription (i.e. one shot payment)
it should support a user management (aka roles, so I can set the privileges of the users)
the login should be with email/password by default and, if any, only optionally with the 2FA or other "human verification" protections
it should provide an issue handling
project and subprojects handling (just a visual/logic representations, useful to allow each customer to access only to their repo)

Just a side note: the front-end GUI I'm talking about is just to easily browse the code across repositories/branches/commits. I'm not interested in editing online or deployment/testing features.
I'm aware that GitLab offers a self-hosting but if its login is like the cloud-based one it enables by default both human verification and 2FA.
From this answer I visited the homepages of gogs and gitea, but both have the demo pages not working and it's not a good sign for me and also both seem to not supporting groups/subprojects.
From this one I see RhodeCode and the Community Edition but it seems to lack the issue feature and from what I understand it seems it does not handle the subprojects as well.

You might wish to take a look at forgejo which should meet most of your requirements. To see it in action, just visit Codeberg.org which runs on Forgejo. Forgejo is a (hard) fork of Gitea.
